Freezeing part of presale tokens
along with a group of friends we want to launch a token on the Solana ecosystem. We have a well-thought-out idea of what the token will be used for and I think it will work out. What I'm coming to you with is the technicalities, more specifically, whether I can implement a Presale for early investors without listing on a e.g.dex screener, without extensive developer knowledge or at a relatively low cost for such a developer, and lock up their tokens so that they can then only sell 30% of their tokens on listing, and then release the next 30% of tokens after e.g. 3 months?

So the TLDR answer is no, not without reasonably extensive developer knowledge. What you're describing is much like what the Mad Lads NFTs are doing with Wormhole, implementing a custom vesting schedule. It's possible to implement a transfer hook with Token Extensions that does this, but you would have to develop and deploy a contact that would implement your custom logic.
If you wanted to do it though, the steps would be

make a token that calls a smart contract with token extensions.
have the smart contract check whether the wallet has used up their 30% day one allotment, and if not allow the transaction
if they have, have it check whether 3 months have elapsed since token launch and allow up to the next 30%, and so on.

